# How to access the INTERNAL ip of a Google Compute Engine instance from outside?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My VM instance is running a console application that listens on port 1313. I need to receive a request to this application from the outside, but it does not work for me ... I imagine it like this: a request comes to the external ip-address of the VM, which is redirected to the internal IP address that my console app is running with. I would be grateful even for hints in which direction to look.

[VPC firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfa8z.png)

Comment: Your question needs more context on your problem and desired solution. If your VM does not have a public IP address, then you will need to use a VPN or forwarder. For a VPN, use OpenVPN, WireGuard, or similar. For forwarding, use Google Cloud IAP for TCP Forwarding. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding Of course, the simplest solution is to add an external public IP address to your VM.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm sorry that did not elaborate. The VM has a public ip-address, but when sending packets with data to the public ip, they do not reach the program located on the VM. As I understand it, I need to forward packets to the internal ip-address of the VM, but I could not find how to do this.

Comment: Most likely your problem is a VPC firewall ingress rule that does not allow traffic on port 1313. When you assign a public IP address to a compute instance, Google assigns a special one-to-one NAT which automatically forwards traffic from the public interface to the private interface. Besides creating an allow firewall ingress rule, there is no other forwarding required.  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, thanks for the help. The problem turned out to be just the same in the firewall. Before that, I created rules through the Console and it turns out that they were not applied after creation! Created by gcloud with the option --enable-logging and it worked.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `--enable-logging`. Be careful with enabling logging on a VPC firewall rule. That could create a large number of logs in Cloud Logging that you would pay for (apx $0.50 per GB).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Helped by the creation of firewall rules gcloud, namely the option --enable-logging. Read more here https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls